# How to abstract the data and control to support easy extensibility?

Tags: scala, traits

I have a case: 
There is `SomeNode`, which is composed by different basic parts: say some types of `A,B,C`. There is also a transformation function that will transform an instance of `SomeNode` to another `SomeNode`.

However, there can be some other parts added to `SomeNode`, in addition to `A,B,C`, so say there might be `D` as the fourth part of the `SomeNode`. and So, the transformation function's interface might also need to change accordingly for the newly added component `SomeNode`, but there might be some same logic shared.

Then I have been wondering, what's a good design to abstract `SomeNode` and its transformation function for easy extensibility? Using trait? how? Some inspiration examples?
Thanks,

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For managing modularity, check out Cake pattern (aka Bakery of Doom pattern). There's been some interesting articles on the topic:

- [Real-World Scala: Dependency Injection (DI)](http://jonasboner.com/2008/10/06/real-world-scala-dependency-injection-di/)
- [Dependency injection vs. Cake pattern](http://www.cakesolutions.net/teamblogs/2011/12/15/dependency-injection-vs-cake-pattern/)
- [Existential Types FTW](http://precog.com/blog-precog-2/entry/existential-types-ftw)
- [Pushing the envelope on OO and functional with Scala](http://debasishg.blogspot.com/2011/03/pushing-envelope-on-oo-and-functional.html)

For managing transformations and traits, Scala compiler is the best example I can think of.

Answer (score 1):

Maybe I'm missing something, but aren't you looking for **inheritance**?

```
class SomeNode(val a: Int, val b: String, val c: Char)

class SpecialNode(from: SomeNode, val d: List[Int]) extends 
         SomeNode(from.a, from.b, from.c)
```

`SpecialNode` shares fields of `SomeNode` and adds new `d` field. The transformation looks something like this (of course it can be more complex:

```
def transform(node: SomeNode) = new SpecialNode(node, Nil)
```

Comment: Maybe I have not explained well. Another thing I am looking for is the other components added can be combined flexibly as needed. FOr example, I may wan to combine `D` and `E`, or just using `E` or `D`. In this case, we just continue to define all the different kinds of subclasses?

Answer (score 1):

I'm hesitant to write this at the expense of showing my noob identity, but based on keywords used in the question, it sounds like '**OOP fundamentals**' are what is being asked for.

**"How to abstract the data and control to support easy extensibility?"** (Generalization)

**"There is SomeNode, which is composed by different basic parts:"** (Aggregation)

**"There is also a transformation function that will transform an instance of SomeNode to another SomeNode."** (Polymorphism)

**"However, there can be some other parts added to SomeNode, in addition to A,B,C, ... function's interface might also need to change accordingly for the newly added component SomeNode, but there might be some same logic shared. "** (Interface)

**"Then I have been wondering, what's a good design to abstract SomeNode and its transformation function for easy extensibility?"** (Inheritance)

Based on my interpretation of the question, I would recommend researching **S.O.L.I.D. design principles**  http://www.youtube.com/watch?NR=1&v=05jVWgKZ6MY&feature=endscreen